# Animate 3d model using LibGDX

Tags: 3d, libgdx, 3d-model

I am about to use LibGDX to create a 3D game.

LibGDX Documentation is very confusing when it comes to 3d , and I cannot understand how to work with 3d models.
Please shed some light on this topic.

There are some examples across the web that doesn't really work or simply outdated.
I know that there is a new 3d API about to be released soon , I don't use it yet , I prefer a stable LibGDX version.

1. **So the first and a very basic things that I need to do is to import a 3d model that I've created in blender (.obj) , and present it with a texture on it.**
2. **The second is to do the same but for animated model , like dude did here in [that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aWZRDR6zYk) video.**

Those are the basics that will help me to get started.
A simple code snippets would be much appreciated.

It would be nice if there was some simple "Hello world" 3d tutorial just to understand how to use LibGDX for 3d scenes.

Comment: Wait like 1-2 weeks. The new 3D Api is on the way. It will be more easy than.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tutorial guides you in using the basics of the 3d api LibGDX offers.

http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/

Comment: Thought I've moved to Unity , this blog is exactly what I needed.I will accept your answer :)